# Card.io cause Non-public API usage

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store, card.io

I got some trouble when I try to upload my app to AppStore.

Apple reject the app with these error message:

---

> **Non-public API usage**:
>
> The app references non-public selectors in MyAppiOS: cardNumber, cardType, libraryVersion, navigationBarStyle, navigationBarTintColor, preload, setCardNumber:, setNavigationBarTintColor:

---

Deep searching told me that the Card.IO is causing the problem, indeed it has all the above selectors.

The same code was uploading successfully. What can be the cause of such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> The same code was uploading successfully. What can be the cause of such behavior?

Apple is continuously updating the checks they do on submitted applications. This means that re-submitting a new version, even with a trivial change, can sometimes end up rejected because of the *new* checks.

Your best bet is to ensure you're using the latest version of the library. An update might already be available for you - unless you're in the first people affected. In the later case you should file an issue with the developer or, since it's open source, re-compile a version of the library that excludes those symbols.